# CSS transition is instant and not fading into the transition

Tags: html, css

I've experienced so many issues whilst trying to come up with a comprehensible User Interface and a vast amount of design changes, however, up until recently, the `transition` property is acting abnormally.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";.header{top:0;position: fixed;right: 0;left:0;background: #555;height: 50pt;border-top: 4pt solid #333;box-shadow: 0 0 5pt  #000}.header-menu{vertical-align: top;margin-top: -12pt;}.header-menu ul li{list-style: none;display: inline}.header-menu ul li a{color:#fff;display: inline-block;line-height: 50pt;padding: 0 10pt;text-decoration: none;transition: all .60s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);-webkit-transition: all .60s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);-moz-transition: all .60s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);-ms-transition: all .60s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);-o-transition: all .60s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);}.header-menu ul li a:hover{background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)}
```

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en-GB" style="">
 <head>
  <base href="http://localhost/">
    <!-- <base href="http://www.icodefoundation.com/"> -->
   <meta charset="UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="refresh"  content="60" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Public/Assets/Styling/All.css" />
   <title>iCode Foundation</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="header header-desktop header-mobile-compatible">
     <div class="header-menu global-menu-styling" role="menu">
       <ul>
         <li role="menuitem"><a href="/PHP">Home</a></li>
         <!-- <li role="menuitem"><a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a></li> -->
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Volunteer</a></li>
         <!--<li role="menuitem"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Reports</a></li>-->
       </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="content_0">
        <div class="same-styling override-same-styles" id="forms">
           <h1>Getting Started</h1>
           Either register or login below to get started.<br>To read more about this website, click <a href="javascript:void(0)">here</a> if you'd like before continuing.
        <div class="form-wrapper"><div class="login divs-inline">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <!-- Login Start -->
            <form method="POST" action="index.php" role="form">
               <div class="inputs"><div class="errors"></div>
               <input type="text" name="login-uname" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
               <input type="password" name="login-pswd" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
               <button type="submit" role="button" name="login-btn">Login</button>
               </div>
            </form> 
       <!-- Login End -->
       </div>
           <div class="register divs-inline">
              <h2>Register</h2>
              <!-- Register Start -->
              <form method="POST" action="index.php" role="form">
                 <div class="inputs">
                 <div class="errors"></div>
                   <input type="text" name="reg-fname" placeholder="Forename" autocomplete="off"class="fname">
                   <input type="text" name="reg-lname" placeholder="Surname" autocomplete="off" class="lname">
                   <input type="text" name="reg-uname" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
                   <input type="text" name="reg-email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
                   <input type="text" name="reg-confirm-email" placeholder="Confirm Email" autocomplete="off">
                   <input type="password" name="reg-pswd" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
                   <input type="password" name="reg-confirm-pswd" placeholder="Confirm Password" autocomplete="off">
                   <button type="submit" role="button" name="reg-btn">Register</button>
            </div>
         </form>
       <!-- Register End -->
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can only sincerely apologize for the incomprehensible code.

Comment: Please post your code unminified, it makes it extremely difficult to read

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept?

Comment: You've fixed my issue, therefore, nah - nothing else you can do. Perhaps this answer could come in handy for someone else who doesn't know about transitions. Perhaps protect it? How do I make it as a community wiki post?

Comment: Actually, I get a flicker every time I reload the page in Chrome with the transition property. I've even tried _backface-visibility_ and it still won't  go away.

Answer (score 1):

It is the combination of a short *duration*, a short *color step* and the *cubic-bezier* that makes it look like it doesn't work.

Here I changed all of them so you see it actually does work.

*Note, always put the non prefixed properties last*

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
.header {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #555;
  height: 50pt;
  border-top: 4pt solid #333;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5pt #000
}

.header-menu {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: -12pt;
}

.header-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline
}

.header-menu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50pt;
  padding: 0 10pt;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .60s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  -moz-transition: all .60s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  -ms-transition: all .60s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  -o-transition: all .60s cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
  transition: all 1.60s;
}

.header-menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB" style="">

<head>
  <base href="http://localhost/">
  <!-- <base href="http://www.icodefoundation.com/"> -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Public/Assets/Styling/All.css" />
  <title>iCode Foundation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header header-desktop header-mobile-compatible">
    <div class="header-menu global-menu-styling" role="menu">
      <ul>
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="/PHP">Home</a></li>
        <!-- <li role="menuitem"><a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a></li> -->
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Volunteer</a></li>
        <!--<li role="menuitem"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Reports</a></li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content_0">
      <div class="same-styling override-same-styles" id="forms">
        <h1>Getting Started</h1>Either register or login below to get started.<br>To read more about this website, click <a href="javascript:void(0)">here</a> if you'd like before continuing.
        <div class="form-wrapper">
          <div class="login divs-inline">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <!-- Login Start -->
            <form method="POST" action="index.php" role="form">
              <div class="inputs">
                <div class="errors"></div><input type="text" name="login-uname" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"><input type="password" name="login-pswd" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"><button type="submit" role="button" name="login-btn">Login</button></div>
            </form>
            <!-- Login End -->
          </div>
          <div class="register divs-inline">
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <!-- Register Start -->
            <form method="POST" action="index.php" role="form">
              <div class="inputs">
                <div class="errors"></div><input type="text" name="reg-fname" placeholder="Forename" autocomplete="off" class="fname"><input type="text" name="reg-lname" placeholder="Surname" autocomplete="off" class="lname"><input type="text" name="reg-uname" placeholder="Username"
                  autocomplete="off"><input type="text" name="reg-email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off"><input type="text" name="reg-confirm-email" placeholder="Confirm Email" autocomplete="off"><input type="password" name="reg-pswd" placeholder="Password"
                  autocomplete="off"><input type="password" name="reg-confirm-pswd" placeholder="Confirm Password" autocomplete="off"><button type="submit" role="button" name="reg-btn">Register</button></div>
            </form>
            <!-- Register End -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Appreciate this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Is there no way to add a lighter black background?

Comment: @Adam Of course, you can change it how you wish...updated my answer a little. Note though, if the _color change_ and _transition duration_ is to little/short, it might appear as the transition goes immediate

Comment: @Adam If my answer solved your question I would appreciate if you also accepted it